# Deploying containerised node.JS application through mesos-marathon

Tags: node.js, docker, mesos, marathon

I am using Marathon to deploy my Docker containerised node.js application. My Marathon app spec is as follows :

```
 {
  "id": "<some-name>",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 2800,
  "disk": 30720,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "docker": {
      "image": "<some-docker-registry-IP>:5000/<repo>",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "privileged": true,
      "forcePullImage": true,
      "parameters": [
        {
          "key": "net",
          "value": "host"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": <some-port>,
          "hostPort": <some-port>,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "name": null
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "DOCKER"
  }
}
```

The problem however is that this leads to restarting my server where application is deployed once it is out of memory. I need my services to listen on private IP of host machine and that's why I am using `--net=host`.

Is it possible to just kill the task freeing up the memory so that Marathon can re-spawn it without restarting/shutting down server? Or is there any other way to make the Docker container routable to the outside world without using `--net=host`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I think there is a problem with you Node application if it shows a memory leaking behavior. Thats the first point I'd address.

Second one is that you should use something like [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) in your application's Docker image which will take care of restarting you application (in the container itself) when it encounters a problem.

Furthermore, you could implement a [Marathon health endpoint](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/health-checks.html), so that Marathon can recognize that the application actually has problems.

To reach some redundancy, I'd strongly advise that you run at least two instances of the application, and use [Mesos DNS](http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/) and a load balancer like [marathon-lb](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb) on the public slave node(s), which will take care of the routing. This also allows you to use bridged networking if you want to.